# Dynamic Vertical menu question

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want all my dynamic generated php links to be displayed like in example 1 below and when I click on a link which takes 
me to another page all its sub links are displayed like in example 2 and when I click on one of those links all its sub 
links are displayed like in the rest of the examples.

I'm using PHP, MySQL and Jquery for my web site if that helps.

Example 1

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
</ul>
```

Example 2

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
</ul>
```

Example 3

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
</ul>
```

Example 4

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this one should be don on server-side, or is there something that I missed?

Comment: How would I get the links to display like in the examples i already know how to generate all the link.

Comment: you should do it in php. By the way, can you explain `dynamic generated php links`, and what is your background about PHP and jQuery? I may start talking something which will may seem hard to you.

Comment: `How is this a -1?` Someone thinks your question is not clear, maybe.

Comment: Downvoting without commenting is stupid and rude.

Comment: @Reigel I'm some what a novice but if you think its hard a quick example would help very much.

Comment: @Pointy sad but true that lots of SO user really downvotes without explaining.

Comment: @Reigel I'm not really good at titles for my questions sorry:(

Comment: @pirate: Where exactly are you stuck; have you already read your menu structure from the database? If so, how does it look?

Comment: @jeron I can get all the links displayed even all the nested links. I want all my parent links to be displayed but not there children  on the home page and when clicking a link it takes you to another page and I really would like to know how to display all the sub links of the clicked link using PHP I hope this is clear let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want **all my dynamic generated php links** to be displayed like in
>   example 1 below and when I click on a
>   link which **takes me to another page
>   all its sub links are displayed** like
>   in example 2 and when I click on one
>   of those links all its sub links are
>   displayed like in the rest of the
>   examples.

The **bold** part is not so clear.

> ```
> all my dynamic generated php links
> ```

how is it dynamic generated? via ajax? please explain further.

> ```
> takes me to another page all its sub links are displayed
> ```

If clicking a link takes you to another page, then displaying a sublink should be done on server-side. Yes you can do it client-side via jQuery but I think it would be not practical.

Summary.

Use your php to display your sublinks.

## HTML

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a>
          <ul class="active"> <!-- active UL -->
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
</ul>
```

## CSS

```
ul.active ul {
    display: none;
}
```

with that above, use your php skills to add/remove class active to a `ul`. By doing that so, and with the definition of your CSS, any `ul` inside active `ul` is not visible. In above, `Fourth Nested List` will not be shown on page.

---

**update**

```
ul ul {
    display: none;
}
ul.active {
    display: block; /* or display:inline; */
}
```

example

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a>
      <ul>  <!-- this will be hidden and all it's sub ul -->
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="active"> <!-- active UL, this will be displayed on the browser -->
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a>
          <ul class="active"> <!-- this will be shown if it's closest parent ul is active also -->
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a>
              <ul>  <!-- this will be hidden and all it's sub ul -->
                <li><a href="link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.php">Fourth Nested List</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.php">Third Nested List</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Reigel all my links are generated through php and all the links are displayed even all the nested links. I want all my parent links to be displayed but not there children. Yes clicking a link takes you to another page and I really would like to know how to display the sub links using PHP.

Comment: @Reigel What if there is nested list in other parent categories in the first nested list how will i hide those?

Comment: please see update.., first, it will hide all the sub `ul` then if you put `class="active"` to a `ul` that ul will be shown.

Comment: @Reigel now the active class dosn't seem to work for the third and fourth nested list any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: be back in an hour, taking my lunch :)

Comment: play around with this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/N3TdG/) and read comments in it. :)

Comment: I fixed the problem when you were gone but know I'm stuck on something else PHP related. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution i would try is:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a>
   <?php if($page = "Some nested page"): ?>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.php">Second Nested List</a>
      </ul>
   <?php endif; ?>
   </li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
   <li><a href="link.php">First Nested List</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is to always add all sub-menu's (and sub-sub, etc.) to your html and set an active class on the current active main menu, sub-menu, sub-sub-menu, etc.

I would then use css to hide the sub-menu's that don´t fall under an active class.

That way you can easily have your menu's pop-up in the future when somebody hovers or clicks on a parent. If you should ever want that...

Comment: where would I put my active class and how would my css look like for my active class and to hide the rest of the menus and example would help me out very much.